# Is it possible to close every application via a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, taskkill

I already know that the `Taskkill /im` command can close a specified application.
However, can you kill all applications (just the programs, not the background processes and Windows processes) currently running in Windows (so if I had a lot of programs opened, could I kill them all)?

For example, instead of writing a really long script that kills every single program (on my computer), would I be able to do something in the format of `taskkill /all`?

Comment: are you trying to literally kill the system? because not all tasks are killable, and killing some will automatically shutdown/reboot the system. and a user (or even admin) account doesn't have the rights to kill tasks running as `system`.

Comment: Nope, just all the .exe programs. Sorry If I was a bit unspecific

Comment: which would be pretty much everything...

Comment: my bad. I'm thinking about the programs that run on the desktop and can be viewed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
wmic process get caption
```

This will return the names of running processes. Use those names to `taskkill /m` them, this should at least kill those processes you opened. For some it might be necessary to `/f`orce killing them.

But beware: you might be closing yourself, so perhaps a more elaborate approach is needed which will make sure you don't kill yourself ;-)

Comment: process suicide, wild stuff!

Comment: @jxramos a massacre, literally ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can add other exe to exclude such as smsss.exe and wininit.exe

```
wmic process where (caption^<^>'svchost.exe' and caption^<^>'csrss.exe') get /format:list
```

This terminates all notepads

```
wmic process where caption='notepad.exe' call terminate
```

Comment: For Vista+ you should probably exclude all process from session 0 (Services). It's also a good idea to exclude executables from session 1+ (Console/interactive sessions) that are located in the Windows directory such as winlogon.exe and explorer.exe. For example: `wmic process where "(SessionId!=0 and not ExecutablePath like "%SystemRoot:\=\\%^%")" get Name`.

Comment: I suggest that you give a more elaborate explanation, even though I understand it. Just a thought for the future (goes to trigger)